# How do I solve the in fragment problem in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home;
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.settings;
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, settingsFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

---

This code "case R.id.home" & "case R.id.settings" I'm getting an error somewhere in this code. it gives this error: ':' or '->' expected

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV25x3a55pk

I'm trying to do it with this video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `case R.id.home;` to `case R.id.home:` (semi-colon to colon). Same for R.id.settings. As in:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, settingsFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that you may then also get a *warning* about "non-final resource ids" in "switch case statements explored further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120822/resource-ids-will-be-non-final-by-default-in-android-gradle-plugin-version-8-0).

One solution to eliminate the anticipated warning is as follows:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, settingsFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Btw, the video did have it as colons.